# extract array of arrays in presto

Tags: struct, presto, amazon-athena, unnest, trino

I have a table in Athena (presto) with just one column named `individuals` and this is the type of then column:

```
array(row(individual_id varchar, ids array(row(type varchar, value varchar, score integer))))
```

I want to extract `value` from inside the `ids` and return them as a new array. As an example:

```
[{individual_id=B1Q, ids=[{type=H, value=efd3, score=1}, {type=K, value=NpS, score=1}]}, {individual_id=D6n, ids=[{type=A, value=178, score=6}, {type=K, value=NuHV, score=8}]}]
```

and I want to return

```
ids
[efd3, NpS, 178, NuHV]
```

I tried multiple solutions like

```
select * from "test"
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(individuals.ids.value) AS t(i)
```

but always return

```
 Expression individuals is not of type ROW
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  array_agg(ids.value)
from test
cross join unnest(test.individuals) t(ind)
cross join unnest(ind.ids) t(ids)
```

result:

```
[efd3, NpS, 178, NuHV]
```

that will return all the id values as one row, which may or may not be what you want

if you want to return an array of individual values by individual_id:

```
select
  ind.individual_id,
  array_agg(ids.value)
from test
cross join unnest(test.individuals) t(ind)
cross join unnest(ind.ids) t(ids)
group by
  ind.individual_id
```